# Can I use a GitHub Action to patch pull requests before running validating actions?

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, github-actions, pipeline

When a collaborator creates/updates a pull request against my repository's default branch I want two things to happen in a specific order:

1. Automatic code formatting + commit formatting changes to the PR branch
2. Run code quality tests and unit tests

If tests complete without errors the default branch's branch protection rules should allow merging.

The problem is that when step 1 completes, the current workflows are now invalid since there is a new commit on the PR branch. Because of this, the results of the tests can not validate the PR, rendering the PR impossible to merge.

Step no. 1 does not trigger another round of Actions since it was committed and pushed by an Action itself and that behavior would just create an endless loop of Actions anyways.

What I want is a way to run step no. 1 automatically before anything else happens so that simple warnings get squashed without developers having to do anything manually.

I am trying to avoid doing this through pre-commit hooks since that would require developers to manually set up their environments the same way.

How can I create the flow I am describing by using GitHub Actions?

Answer (score 0):

Since we don't have the actual action script I can only assume what steps it performs, and in what order (see the details under TL;DR).

The true issue is that your action is failing the *separation of concerns* principle, i.e. it is doing validation (code quality analysis, read-only) as it should, but it is also doing modification (code formatting correction).

Code formatting is, in general, a task more suited for a `pre-commit` or `pre-push` hook instead. If badly formatted code does get pushed, **code formatting check should fail the build instead of auto-correcting it**.

#### TL;DR

A simplified example... The `origin` repository is `github.com/example/app`, the pull request is for the branch `new-feature`, and the action looks something like this:

```
steps:
  - name: Checkout repository (1)
    uses: actions/checkout

  - name: Check code formatting (2)
    run: run-lint -autofix && git add . && git commit "formatted"

  - name: Run tests and check code quality (3)
    run: run-tests && run-sonar

  - name: Merge it (4)
    ...
```

When a contributor pushes changes to the `new-feature` branch a build will be triggered, and it will be done by e.g. GitHub's `build-bot-42`.

The `build-bot-42` will go through the action's steps in order:

- **(1)** get a copy of the code in question onto itself - `build-bot-42` is not the same computer as the one storing GitHub's git repository. The `checkout` action will basically do the following:

  ```bash
  cd ${unique-temp-dir}
  git init
  git fetch --all
  git checkout origin/new-feature
  ```
- **(2)** run a *lint* tool in auto-correct mode, and then apply the changes in a `git commit`.
- **(3)** run tests and the static code analysis.

If all checks pass we have a local git repository ready to be **merged and pushed** to `origin` (in that order).

Of course, **if the tests and/code quality don't pass the pull request still has the badly formatted code** because the action didn't push the code formatting  changes.